NGINX - Unable to set `proxy_max_temp_file_size` greater than 1024m
I am using NGINX on Windows as a reverse proxy to a library endpoint. I want to increase the value in the proxy_max_temp_file_size directive to serve some of my larger libraries.
However, setting proxy_max_temp_file_size to a value above 1024m gives me the following error:
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_max_temp_file_size" directive invalid value in path/to/nginx.conf:178

Here is the full nginx.conf
#user  nobody;
worker_processes 2;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    # upstream endpoint
    upstream pypi-gpu {
        server localhost:9500;
    }

    server {
        listen 9000 ssl;
        server_name pythonlibs.mydomain.com;

        ssl_certificate "path/to/cert.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "path/to/private.key";
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location / {
            proxy_max_temp_file_size 3072m;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://pypi-gpu;
        }
    }
}

Note that setting proxy_max_temp_file_size 0 allows me to serve large files but I'd prefer to keep this bounded if possible.
nginx version: nginx/1.27.0

Looks like a Windows thing perhaps. Just gave it a try on 1.22.0 on Ubuntu, worked like a charm.
